# setting the date on load up of a calendar

Tags: jquery

I have looked at some examples on here about how to set the date for a calendar however they don't seem to work or I am missing something very obvious (the more likely case).

But how do you set the date in calendar? the two examples below are what I have seen on previous posts.

A fiddle [if it helps](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/535842/)

```
<div><input id="dtSelectorStatic" type="date"/></div>
```

**jquery 1st attempt**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker();
$("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));

})
```

**jquery 2nd attempt**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

$("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    defaultDate: date,
    onSelect: function () {
        selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    }
});

$("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", date);
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/thecreativedev/v8w3457s/

You have not added jquery ui file into the demo so datepicker was not working. Otherwise your way to set date is correct.

```
<div><input id="dtSelectorStatic" type="date"/></div>
```